# Is it possible to perform an update to a Windows partition without manually booting into the partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, partitioning, windows-update

Specifically I'm dealing with Windows 10 and 7 partitions (mostly 10). I suspect, due to being unable to turn anything up in my searching, that the answer is a resounding "No" possibly followed up with "It would cause too many security issues to allow this sort of thing" (which, fair enough, is probably accurate) but I figured I'd at least ask just in case.

It would rather nice to update across all partitions on a PC at once though, particularly for systems with large numbers of partitions.

Edit: To clarify, each partition has a different version of Windows installed, so performing updates for all versions of Windows on a given system is very time consuming if done manually by booting into each partition and then performing the updates.

Additionally, this is specifically Windows OS updates (eg. anything that checking for updates would pull in). Sorry for not stating that originally.

Comment: Yes. This is easily done with `dism` install any windows updates or packages you want to an offline partition.

Comment: @Appleoddity - Any update except **Feature Updates.**. Those can only be installed within Windows.  What does the number of partitions have to do with installing Windows updates?